# What's the code to get 30 lives in the original Contra?

Tags: cheats, contra

There was a code you entered into Contra for NES to get 30 extra lives.  You entered it with the controller.  What was it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[The Konami code:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konami_Code)

<kbd>↑</kbd> <kbd>↑</kbd> <kbd>↓</kbd> <kbd>↓</kbd> <kbd>←</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd> <kbd>←</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>Start</kbd>

or for 2-player

<kbd>↑</kbd> <kbd>↑</kbd> <kbd>↓</kbd> <kbd>↓</kbd> <kbd>←</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd> <kbd>←</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>Select</kbd> <kbd>Start</kbd>

(technically, the "Start" and "Select, Start" are not part of the code, but are necessary to start the game)

Comment: Accepted: first one, plus included the select, start info.

Answer (score 23):

The [Konami code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konami_Code).

[image]

Comment: Too bad the image is too wide for this layout.

Answer (score 6):

Technically the code is:

- up up down down left right left right b a

and select changed the mode to two players, and then start started the game, but the "[select] start" is generally referred as part of the code. This code is referred to as "The Konami Code", "The Contra Code", or simply "The Code"

Answer (score -2):

The code (rendered in HTML) is:

<kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>←</kbd><kbd>→</kbd><kbd>←</kbd><kbd>→</kbd><kbd>Ⓑ</kbd><kbd>Ⓐ</kbd><kbd>Start</kbd>

Comment: This adds absolutely nothing that hasn't already been said.

Answer (score -2):

For2 players, and I could be wrong, which I usually am. I remember, up up, down down,left right, left right, b a b a, select, start. But its been a minute for me. :/

Comment: The question is about 5 years old and has multiple answers already, including what you just wrote. Adding another answer isn't technicly wrong, but don't be surprised if yours no longer gets any positive attention.

Answer (score -3):

Another representation of the code, which is responsible for me knowing it by heart without ever having played Contra:  [The Gothsicles - Konami Code IV](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rs53c0q6kHg)

Answer (score -4):

The actually code was up up down left right left right A B A B select start and you had to to it at the very beginning before the game actually loaded to the screen to ask how many players

Answer (score -4):

Up down up down left right left right B A
 select start

Answer (score -7):

I played this game in 86' The code was Up, up, down, down, left right left right a b b a. You had to enter it really fast at the beginning of the game.

Comment: This is not the correct code.

Comment: You might be conflating this with the Ikari Warriors "ABBA" code to come back to life after dying.