# What is that Up Up Down Down code thing?

Tags: cheats

I remember back in the day there was a Up Up Down Down cheat code that was used in a lot of things.

1. What's the full code?
2. Is there a name for this code?
3. Are there any games where this code works? (nostalgia value)

Comment: b-a-start as a tag? :P

Comment: This is an exact dupe:  http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/395/whats-the-code-to-get-30-lives-in-the-original-contra

Comment: I wouldn't call this an exact dupe of that question, since that one relies on knowing what the code does or is from to be searchable.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is called the Konami Code, its

↑ ↑ ↓ ↓ ← → ← → B A

And it works on quite a few games, and even some websites.

A wikilink to those lists are:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Konami_code_games

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Konami_code_websites

Comment: I seem to remember a "select start" added on to the end for a couple of the game boy games.

Comment: @Jeffrey, that's how many of it used to memorize it, but it's not technically part of the code- the "Start" is just what actually starts the game, and you add the "Select" to move the indicator from One- to Two-Player if you're playing with someone else.

Comment: No, I clearly remember having to hit "start" or "select start" in some games to activate the code (ex. TMNT).  It did not start the game.

Comment: If you tell me you have a keyboard with keys to enter those arrow shapes, I'll rep you to heavens.

Comment: @Bora I wish, they don't even have ALT+#### input options.

Answer (score 10):

It's the [Konami code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konami_Code). [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Konami_code_games) are games where it can be used.

[image: Konami Code]